# Filter fragment adapter from action bar

Tags: java, android, filter, adapter, searchview

**Edited...**

I am trying to filter an adapter from a search view. I know what I have is close, but not quite there. I am getting this error message, with the code below.

**LogCat**

```
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40f0f2a0)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException at ---$FreeAgentPagerAdapter.getCount(---.java:403)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:813)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2688)
    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
    at ---$FreeAgentPagerAdapter$1.publishResults(---.java:434)
```

**SearchView**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.in_game, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    setupSearchView(searchItem);

    if (mState == 0) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
    }

    return true;
}

private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

    if (isAlwaysExpanded()) {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    } else {
        searchItem.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    }

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}

String newText = "";
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Query = " + newText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Adapter.getFilter().filter(newText.toString());
    return false;
}

protected boolean isAlwaysExpanded() {
    return false;
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        ViewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Pager);
        Adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        ViewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
        return rootView;
    }
}

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List TITLES = new ArrayList();

    private Map ReferenceMap;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

        ReferenceMap = new HashMap();

        TEST.add("TESTING");
        for (Test test : test.getTest()) {
            TEST.add(test.getTest());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getTitle(int i) {
        return TEST.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TEST.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment Fragment = Fragment.newInstance(test.getId(), TEST.get(i));
        ReferenceMap.put(i, (Fragment) Fragment);
        return Fragment;
    }

    public FiltaddDropFragmentlter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                Toast. makeText(getBaseContext(), "Publishing " + constraint, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TEST = (List<String>) results.values;
                Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Filtering " + constraint, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                List<String> filteredResults = getFilteredResults(constraint);

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filteredResults;

                return results;
            }
        };
    }

}

private List<String> getFilteredResults(CharSequence constraint) {
    return null;
}
```

Would anyone be able to point out what I'm doing wrong? I think I just need a second pair of eyes to look this over. What should I be doing differently and how can I do this the best way?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to filter.

Comment: I am trying to filter mAddDropAdapter with the keyword from the search view. What isn't clear about the code?

Comment: I've missed that part. In the `performFiltering()` method you use the `getFilteredResults(constraint);` method to get the filtered values but you've setup it to always return `null`. In there you would want to  iterate over the `TITLES` list and see which one matches the constraint(and add those entries to a results list and return it instead of null). Also, the Filter class is not quite required, it would be used when filtering the adapter of an AdapterView. In your case you could make the filtering in a simple method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps:

1. Make a new class (or perhaps a static inner class in your adapter) that extends [`Filter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html). Implement the [`performFiltering()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#performFiltering%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.
2. Implement the [`publishResults()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#publishResults%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.Filter.FilterResults%29) method to exchange your list data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter
3. Make your adapter implement the `Filterable` interface and define the `getFilter()` method. It should return an instance of your new filter class that you made in step 1.

`performFiltering` will be processed on a background thread, and `publishResults` will be called from the UI thread.

I'm looking for the sample code that helped me learn list filtering. If I find it I'll post a link.

Comment: Thank you for the step-by-step. I would appreciate it if you would post the link.

Comment: It's not the same one I found before, but here's an example: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

Comment: Would you mind taking another look at my question? I updated it.

Comment: Your `getCount()` implementation doesn't work if `TITLES` is `null`. Either change it to `return (TITLES != null) ? TITLES.size(): 0;` or make sure your filter always swaps in a non-null List (it can be an empty list).

Comment: Okay. It's working now. Do you know the best way to make the filter case insensitive? Some of the words are capitalized and won't show in the results unless your keyword matches exactly.

Comment: use `toLowerCase()` on both the filter argument and the item you are testing before doing your comparison.